# How to close all child frames from parent frame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, multiple-instances

I am now working with an application.
In that there are lots of child `JFrame` objects there.
Each time the button to show child frame is clicked a new instance of child frame is created and hence multiple copies of same child frame is created.

How can I prevent multiple copies of child node?

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to track whether child frame has already opened with button click. If it is, then dont create new form. If not create new child form and display it.

Or if your bussiness logic permits then, go for model dialogs. But better you ask your manager.

And as `manoj` pointed out, you can use `boolean` data types to flag displaying new form.

Answer (score 2):

You can have boolean flag to store jframe state. Based on this flag u can prevent of creating multiple instance of JFrame.

Comment: then how can i fetch the child frame to front

Comment: can you get me any link or some thing like that

Comment: And there are one more problem that child frame is not object of a single class. may object of different class